# Projection or Custom Value Resolvers with new Multi Lingual Mappings

Tags: asp.net-core, automapper, aspnetboilerplate

I am using the newest version of ASP.Net Boilerplate (version 3.7.2). I am currently using the new Multi-Lingual Entities.

I am having issues with the Automapping for 1 of the Entities to a Dto as not only does it require the Multi-Lingual aspect but a Projection/Custom Resolver for one of the properties.

Up to this point all the mappings have been working correctly. I have followed the documentation found at [ASP.NET Boilerplate Documentation](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Lingual-Entities)

```cs
[Table("CategoryItems")]
public class CategoryItem : BaseClass, IMultiLingualEntity<CategoryItemTranslation>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Category Item Display Order
    /// </summary>
    public int DisplayOrder { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Catalog Categories
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<CatalogItem> CatalogItems { get; set; } = new HashSet<CatalogItem>();

    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets all the Entity Translations
    /// </summary>
    public virtual ICollection<CategoryItemTranslation> Translations { get; set; } = new HashSet<CategoryItemTranslation>();
}


[Table("CategoryItemTranslations")]
public class CategoryItemTranslation : IEntityTranslation<CategoryItem>
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Get or Set Category Item Name
    /// </summary>
    public string CategoryItemName { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Link to Category Item
    /// </summary>
    public CategoryItem Core { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets Link to Core Id
    /// </summary>
    public int CoreId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets the Language
    /// </summary>
    public string Language { get; set; }
}


public class ReadCategoryItemFilterDto : PhantomEntityDto
{
    public string CategoryItemName { get; set; }

    ...

    public int ItemCount { get; set; }

    ...
}
```

Using the Create MultiLingual Map code within the Initialize of the ApplicationModule class:

```cs
cfg.CreateMultiLingualMap<CategoryItem, CategoryItemTranslation, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto>(new MultiLingualMapContext(IocManager.Resolve<ISettingManager>()));
```

The CategoryItemName from the Translation Entity correctly maps to the CategoryItemName on the ReadCategoryItemFilterDto.

Now I need to map the CatalogItems Count to the ItemCount on the Dto.

I have tried adding to the Mapping Configurator:

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<CategoryItem, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemCount, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.CatalogItems.Count));
```

and

```cs
cfg.CreateMap<CategoryItem, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.ItemCount, opts => opts.ResolveUsing(new CatalogItemFilterCountResolver()));
```

using

```cs
public class CatalogItemFilterCountResolver : IValueResolver<CategoryItem, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto, int>
{
    public int Resolve(CategoryItem source, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto destination, int m, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return source.CatalogItems.Count;
    }
}
```

If I add this map before the CreateMultiLingualMap the CatalogItemName Maps correctly but the ItemCount fails.
If I put the Projection or Resolver after the CreateMultiLingualMap then the ItemCount maps correctly but the CatalogItemName fails to map.

How do I create a Map Profile to allow for both of the properties to be mapped?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your case, you don't need to use the extension `CreateMultiLingualMap`.
You can create your own mapping definition with multilingual mapping included.

That's how it is done;

```cs
configuration.CreateMap<CategoryItem, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto>()
    .BeforeMap((source, destination, context) =>
    {
        var translation = source.Translations.FirstOrDefault(pt => pt.Language == CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.Name);
        if (translation != null)
        {
            context.Mapper.Map(translation, destination);
            return;
        }


        var multiLingualMapContext = new MultiLingualMapContext(IocManager.Instance.Resolve<ISettingManager>());
        var defaultLanguage = multiLingualMapContext.SettingManager.GetSettingValue(LocalizationSettingNames.DefaultLanguage);

        translation = source.Translations.FirstOrDefault(pt => pt.Language == defaultLanguage);

        if (translation != null)
        {
            context.Mapper.Map(translation, destination);
            return;
        }

        translation = source.Translations.FirstOrDefault();
        if (translation != null)
        {
            context.Mapper.Map(translation, destination);
        }

    }).ForMember(dest => dest.ItemCount, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.CatalogItems.Count));
```

Comment: Thank you, however this still errors on the Automap between the CategoryItemTranslation Entity and the ReadCategoryItemFilterDto. It is not happy with the unmapped properties including the ItemCount. I tried adding ForMember for all these properties to no avail.

Comment: you need to ignore all the not existing properties in your dto `.Ignore(record => record.Field)`

Comment: I have tried adding `.ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());` after the BeforeMap. However, the error is still suggesting the mapping fails within the BeforeMap at Line `context.Mapper.Map(translation, destination)`. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, I have worked this out. I also had to add another Map between the Transaltion Entity and the Dto as well as the accepted answer. So in my case: `cfg.CreateMap<CategoryItemTranslation, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto>()
                    .ForMember(dest => dest.CategoryItemName, opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.CategoryItemName))
                    .ForAllOtherMembers(opts => opts.Ignore());` was required. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Multi-Lingual-Entities#createmultilingualmap

```
configuration.CreateMultiLingualMap<CategoryItem, CategoryItemTranslation, ReadCategoryItemFilterDto>(context)
.EntityMap.ForMember(dest => dest.ItemCount, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.CatalogItems.Count));
```

Comment: This addresses the problem in the latest version of the framework. However, this was not possible in the version (v3.7.2) I was developing in at the time.